# Bridging an open public wifi (xfinitywifi) to a virtual machine

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, bridge

I have a virtualbox VM that I want to bridge xfinitywifi to. I'm connected to ethernet, and then xfinitywifi using a pcie wifi (so I can't do USB passthrough for the wifi). Using windows 10 as host.

**xfiniywifi info:**
You connect to the unsecured AP "xfinitywifi", then you have to sign with your xfinity account on a web browser to gain access to the internet. It then saves the wifi card's mac address so it will connect to the internet automatically next time it connects. I assume most public wifi's with login pages may work this way.

**VM Bridging info:**

-Under Network options, If I choose NAT, The VM defaults to the ethernet connection (and does connect to the internet).

-If I choose Bridged adapter, and choose the ethernet connection, it also works.

-If I choose to bridge my wifi, and connect to my routers normal AP ("MyHomeWifi" for example), the VM does connect to internet correctly.

-However, If the wifi is connected to an xfinitywifi hotspot, and I bridge that, the VM CANNOT connect to the internet.

---

So I'm assuming it's something with the way it authenticates? Or that it needs a static IP setup in someway, but I don't know the right settings if so. - I tried making the VM a static IP with he same details as the wifi connection, that didn't work :(

**ONE WORKAROUND**
Using [Windows 10 mobile hotspot feature](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/use-your-windows-pc-as-a-mobile-hotspot-c89b0fad-72d5-41e8-f7ea-406ad9036b85), if I share my internet from wifi (which is connected to xfinitywifi), windows creates
*Wifi Direct Virtual Adapter", and I am able to bridge from that successfully in my VM.

Answer (score 0):

Wi-Fi doesn't quite support bridging; the access point won't let your computer report any other "source MAC" except that which actually connected to the AP.

VirtualBox makes it work by transparently translating the VMs' MAC addresses to the host's MAC (basically performing "layer2 NAT"). So Xfinity sees two IP addresses using the same MAC address. With normal networks this still works fine.

But with Wi-fi networks that use website-form logins, it is very likely that they authorize the *specific combination* of the MAC and IP address that was seen by the login website at that time. As the VM's IP address is different, but it still borrows the host's MAC, the network might be deliberately filtering it out as "address spoofing".

(Such networks are all different from each other, but it's quite possible that e.g. the system uses two separate firewall rules for each client, and the "allow internet access" rule doesn't trigger because the VM's IP is not authorized, and the "redirect to website" rule also doesn't trigger because it thinks the VM's MAC *is* authorized... That's just an example.)

The "Wi-Fi Direct" feature most likely works because it actually associates to the Xfinity AP twice, with different MAC addresses.

Comment: I don't think it associates with a different mac address, because only 10 mac addresses are allowed per xfinity account and I already have all 10 used.
I tried to change the IP address and Mac of the VM to the host wifi, still didn't work